# What is this requirement on IP addresses of different interfaces on the same server computer?

Tags: networking

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Internet_sharing

> **2.1 Static IP address**
>
> On the server computer, assign a static IPv4 address to the interface
> connected to the other machines. **The first 3 bytes of this address
> cannot be exactly the same as those of another interface, unless both
> interfaces have netmasks strictly greater than /24.**
>
> ```
> # ip link set up dev net0
> # ip addr add 192.168.123.100/24 dev net0 # arbitrary address
> ```

What does "The first 3 bytes of this address cannot be exactly the same as those of another interface, unless both interfaces have netmasks strictly greater than /24" mean?
Does it mean that the networks of different interfaces on the server computer must not overlap?

Why is the requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This description is practically true while being technically incorrect as well as vague and poorly written.

For a class C networks, the first three bytes of the IP address are the network address.  Many networks are class C, but there are also class A and class B networks which this description omits as well as "netmasks strictly greater than /24", so it is at least wrong by omission.  But it is also wrong for other reasons.

To describe this in a more technically accurate and detailed way, the IP address is divided into two parts, the network address, and the machine address.  These are segregated by the netmask.  A netmask of /24 corresponds to the IP address 255.255.255.0.  If, for instance, the IP address was 192.168.100.1/24 then the network address (applying the netmask) would be `192.168.100.0` and the machine address portion would be `.1`.  A class B network address would be /16 or 255.255.0.0 with a network address of `192.168` and machine address portion of `.100.1`.  Similarly a class A address corresponds to a netmask of /8.

The number after the / indicates the number of bits on the left of the IP address that are part of the network address.  Netmask sizes between /2 and /32 are technically possible but only between /8 and /29 are practical.

So, what the text in the question is implying is that you can't have two interfaces on the same machine with the same network address.  Traditionally, if you did this, then network traffic sent out of the machine would not know which interface to use to get to the network.

However, even this is wrong.  It is possible (and trivial) to fix this problem by giving the interfaces priorities, so that one of them is always chosen as primary.  But then traffic sent to the second interface from outside would prefer being answered by the first interface, and outside machines would not like getting a response from an IP address different than the one the traffic was sent to.

But even this can be fixed.  Modern operating systems allow tagging of incoming traffic by interface, so that the responses are sent out on the same interface it came in on, making it fully possible to have two interfaces with two different IP addresses but the same network address (and on the same network) that are fully functional.

Also, it is possible to use bonding and teaming to group multiple interfaces together under the same IP address on the same network.  This must be supported by both the host operating system and the upstream switch.  There are two reasons to do this: 1) to allow redundant interfaces, so if one fails, others can take over 2) to allow bandwidth sharing between interfaces to increase the bandwidth of the host beyond the max throughput for a single interface.

In conclusion, the statement quoted in the question may have been partially correct at some time in the past when IP routing inside the operating system was much simpler and bonding and teaming didn't exist.  But even then, the statement is very poorly worded and doesn't
include the cases where network addresses could be smaller than /24 and doesn't explain why.   With today's networking, the statement is just completely wrong.

Also note that even very early versions of linux supported routing multiple interfaces to the same network (although the configuration of this has changed several times), and very early versions of linux also supported bonding and teaming.  Both of these features likely predate Arch linux, so unless this paragraph was taken out of context that explained this, then it was likely never correct.

Having said that, configuring multiple interfaces to use the same network is complex and tricky, so in a simple configuration, it is necessary for each interface to have a different network address, making the statement practical, even if not correct.

Comment: _Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing